# Highcharts on .net server

Tags: c#, .net, highcharts

I made webforms app that draws graphs. I did all of that client-side using Highcharts. Now I need to graphs, every week, for previous week, by mail. All of this should be done without rendering graph to DOM. Can I get SVG string from Highcharts.net? I can generate PDF easily with SVG string.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use Highcharts Node.js Export Server. It allows you to send requests to the server and get pdfs directly from it.

Check github and docs for getting more configuration information:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server
https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server